# Dynamic Achievement System algorithm / design

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures

I'm developing this Achievement System and it must have a CRUD, that admins access to create new achievements and it's rules. I need some help with the design & algorithm of this so it can easily evolve with new rules as admins ask.

#### Rules sample

**Medal one**: must complete 5 any courses with a score of at least 90
**Medal two**: must complete two specific courses with a score of at least 85
**Medal three**: must be top 5 in general ranking at least once
**Medal four**: must have more than 5000 points

I'll basically store that as metadata in a relational database, probably with these columns below:

- action
- action quantity
- course quantity
- score
- id course
- ranking
  position
- points

I want to know if there is any known algorithm / design to this kind of problem? Or perhaps I should store them differently to make it easier? Don't know, I want suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your doubts may be right. In my opinion, a database is the wrong way to organize this data. Every new kind of achievement you want to create would add extra columns to your database, and most achievements wouldn't use most of the columns. A more flexible data structure, one that doesn't expect for every entry to use all of the possible achievement criteria at once by default, would probably be more useful. Most languages support [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp), so I suggest you use that. The structure could be something like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Medal One",
    "requirements": {
      "coursesCompleted": 5,
      "scoreMin": 90
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Medal Two",
    "requirements": {
      "specificCoursesCompleted": [
        "Course 1",
        "Course 2"
      ],
      "scoreMin": 85
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Medal Three",
    "requirements": {
      "generalRankingMin": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Medal Four",
    "requirements": {
      "scoreMin": 5000
    }
  }
]
```

You can see here how the criteria types are sometimes reused, but they can be omitted when not needed and new ones can be added to a few achievements without bloating the rest of the dataset as well.

PS: I made the criteria names very verbose for demonstration purposes; shortening them or not in actual use is up to preference.